# how to execute function on dynamically added element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have an ajax post function in jquery. The response of the ajax call is passed to a handler that generates a bunch of `div` elements like so:

```
function handleResponse(data)
{
        $.post( 
            "ajax.php",
            { 
                url: url,
                action: "getProductImages" 
            },
            function(data) 
            {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                newDiv = "";
                jQuery.each(obj, function(key,value) 
                {
                    newDiv += '<div class="product-img-container">\
                    <img src="'+value+'"></div>';
                });
                $("#product-images").empty();
                $(newDiv).appendTo('#product-images');
            }
}
```

As you can see I create new divs with class `product-img-container` and render them inside `product-images` div.

Now I want to run this code on these newly created divs:

```
$('.product-img-container').productThumb();
```

I tried putting this inside `$(document).ready` function,but it does not work there because the divs are not available at that time. I then put this inside my 
`handleResponse` function, as:

```
....
$("#product-images").empty();
$(newDiv).appendTo('#product-images');
$(newDiv).productThumb();
```

Doesn't work either :(

Comment: Stryner has provided a good solution ... and note his comment about chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newDiv` is just a string. When you call `$(newDiv)`, jQuery is creating the DOM elements for you.

The code you tried is doing the following:

```
// Create DOM elements and append to #product-images
$(newDiv).appendTo('#product-images');

// Create DOM elements and attach events. 
// These DOM elements are different! You never attach them to the DOM.
$(newDiv).productThumb();
```

Instead you should create them and use that reference:

```
var $newDiv = $(newDiv);
$newDiv.appendTo('#product-images');
$newDiv.productThumb();
```

Or you could simply chain them:

```
$(newDiv).appendTo('#product-images')
         .productThumb();
```